# Excel: Transpose but keep background colours

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I currently use the following to transpose columns into rows

```
TRANSPOSE(code!A2:C189)
```

This works fine except for the colours do not also get copied across. I can copy > paste special and it keeps them but if I amend any values in the original, I will have to do this every time.

Is there a way to keep the colours from the original whilst transposing in a way I don't have to keep copying/pasting when there is a change?

I realise I can assign this to a Macro as follows but would be nice for it to be automatic

```
 Sheets("code").Select
    Range("A2:C2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("tracker").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Just a thought post shower nackered on me bed: couldn't you read original colours into array, mapping to each l original cell positions . and then paste or apply those colours back to your new table, cell by cell ? It would be a different program. Array based . I wouldn't know how to apply conditional formatting transpose using your method you've used above right now (Though it might be a one liner) . But I think mapping with array would be a surer bet  .so you paste - apply new cells colours based on your transform.

Comment: With cell.address . So for each cell in selection, store that cell address in array & store - read it's colour too . Paste array back transposed